# Perfect squares of form $n!+4$

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

Can $n!+4$ be a perfect square when $n\geq5$?  I tried to check if there is any perfect squares that is form of $n!+4$, but I didn't succeed.

I think $n!+4$ can be a perfect square when $n\geq5$, since $n!+4$ when $n>5$ is $0 \pmod {4}$ and $1 \pmod {3}$.

Comment: $n!+4$ is not a perfect power for the positive integers $n\le 10^5$ , let alone a perfect square. Such problems are in general very difficult. We do not know whether $n!+1$ is a perfect square for some integer $n>7$ (Brocards problem)

Comment: On the other hand, $n!+2$ and $n!+3$ cannot be perfect squares for $n>5\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ ($2$ and $3$ are not quadratic residues mod $5$)

Comment: Any time $n \gt 3, n! \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, so $n!+4 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and you don't have a problem here.

Comment: Also $n!- a^2 = b^2$ has no solutions for $n > 6$, by considering a prime $\equiv 3 \mod 4$ in the interval $[(n+1)/2,n]$.