# Are there any perfect numbers other than $28$ that are of the form of $\,n^3+1\,?$

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers

I am wondering if there is any perfect number that is of the form $\,n^3+1$ (i.e. one more than a perfect cube).

Since perfect number minus one (for example, $495$ and $8127$) $\equiv$ $0\pmod{9}$ and $7\pmod{8}$, are there any perfect numbers that is form of $\,n^3+1$ ? For example, $495$ isn't a perfect cube and $8127$  is not also a perfect cube.

Comment: Yabata, if you do not want your question to be closed by moderators of this website, you should provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: The question might be hard, compare the comments to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617195/perfect-squares-of-form-n4).

Comment: Not sure whether there is a necessary condition for odd perfect numbers ruling out that they are of the form $n^3+1$. But since it is very unlikely that there is an odd perfect number , the below answer almost completely solves the problem.

Comment: Without the below answer , I would have checked the known even perfect numbers (we know them all upto millions of digits) , whether they are of the form $n^3+1$. This can be done if similar questions occur about perfect numbers (whether they can have a specific form).

Comment: One of the answers suggests to generalize this to whether there is another perfect number of the form $x^n+y^n$ with positive integers $x,y,n$. This might be interesting if we rule out $n=1$

Comment: If $P$ is one of the first $45$ known perfect numbers (sorted by magnitude) , then $P+1$ is not a perfect power and $P-1$ only for $P=28$. The $45$ th known perfect number has already more than $22$ million digits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are certainly no *even* perfect numbers other than $\ 28\ $ that are of the form $\ n^3+1\ $.  Every even perfect number must be of the form $\ 2^{p-1}\big(2^p-1\big)\ $ with $\ p\ge2\ $. For $\ p=2\ $, $\ 2^{p-1}\big(2^p-1\big)=6\ $ is *not* of the form $\ n^3+1\ $, while $\ 28=2^2\big(2^3-1\big)=3^3+1\ $ *is* of that form.  If $\ p\ge4\ $, and $\ 2^{p-1}\big(2^p-1\big)\ $ were of that form we would have
\begin{align}
2^{p-1}(2^p-1)&=n^3+1\\
&=(n+1)(n^2-n+1)\ ,
\end{align}
and since $\ n\ $, and hence $\ n^2-n+1\ $ must then be odd, it would have to be the case that $\ 2^{p-1}\,\big|\,n+1\ $—that is $\ n=2^{p-1}k-1\ $ for some positive integer $\ k\ $.  Thus, we would then have
\begin{align}
2^p-1&=k\big(n^2-n+1\big)\\
&=k\big(\big(2^{p-1}k-1\big)^2-2^{p-1}k+1+1\big)\\
&=k\big(k^22^{2p-2}-2^pk+3-2^{p-1}k\big)\\
&=k\big(k2^{p-1}\big(k2^{p-1}-3\big)+3\big)\\
&>2^{p-1}\big(2^3-3)\\
&>2^p\ ,
\end{align}
which is a contradiction.  Therefore, $\ 2^{p-1}\big(2^p-1\big)\ $ is not of the form $\ n^3+1\ $ for any $\ p\ge4\ $,and hence $\ 28\ $ is the only even perfect number of that form.